# How to disable a button on Windows Phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

we are using jquery to disable buttons by adding ui-disbled class , its working in all the mobile devices except windows.

Anybody had similar situation or any work around suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of disabling buttons using `ui-disabled` class, you could use this :

```
$(".selector").buttonMarkup( "disable" );
```

Docs : http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable